# Back button not showing up in design editor

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I had the Activities "MyActivity" and its parent "MainActivity". Everything worked fine.

Then I refactored "MyActivity" and renamed it to "PrimeFactorizationActivity". Since then the back button is missing in the GUI design editor:

[image]

I tried refactoring "activity_my" and renaming it to "activity_prime_factorization", but it didn't work.
Also, I tried removing the parentActivityName-Tag and re-inserting it, but it didn't work either.

I don't see what's wrong with my code. In the Manifest it looks like this:

```
<activity android:name=".PrimeFactorizationActivity"
          android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

What's interesting is that when I build and run the app on a device, the button is visible. Furthermore, if I rename "PrimeFactorizationActivity" back to "MyActivity", the back button reappears.

Comment: how do you know its not working ?

Comment: the back button is missing. I added a screenshot.

Comment: Ok, now I tried running it on an actual device (should have tried this earlier). There it is visible, I updated the Original post.

Comment: Don't trust android studio's GUI editor. Run it on both emulator and a physical device to make sure if everything's working or not